# parsing a date in D3.js with hours, mins and seconds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am starting to experiment with d3, and I am finding a problem with a time conversion when coding in the console. I have a group of data points that represent dates (read from a CSV), that I need to format to time/date.

This works:

```
time = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse("1996-01-04");
```

console returns:

```
Thu Jan 04 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

But this one does not:

```
time = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse("1996-01-04 03:51:58.170");
```

Console returns:

```
null
```

What's the appropriate d3.time format for the my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just left out the miliseconds `.%L`

```
time = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L").parse("1996-01-04 03:51:58.170");
```

See the docs for details: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting